# reading parameter in c

Tags: ros, parameter, parameter-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to read parameters in my program based on this example  http://wiki.ros.org/Parameter%20Server

Here is code snippet

```
std::string my_number;
nh_.getParam("my_number",my_number);

ROS_INFO("\n My Number %s",my_number.c_str());
```

And  I am calling like this
rosrun mypkg my_node my_number:=5

This value is not getting read.

Please help, how can  I read in my C program.

Thanks,
Hemant

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220410/reading-parameter-in-c/) by [hemant T](https://answers.ros.org/users/23015/hemant-t/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`my_number:=5` does NOT set a parameter. It remaps the topic `my_number` to 5.

Either set the parameter on the param server, e.g., via `rosparam set` or use `_my_number:=5` to set a private parameter. In that case you'll also need a private `NodeHandle("~")` before retrieving the parameter.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3